# Unabled to open service Tomcat7

Tags: windows-server-2012, tomcat7

I recently installed Apache Tomcat 7 on Windows Server 2012.  After a reboot, logging in as an administrator generates the following error message:

> Application System Error. Access is denied. Unable to open the service 'Tomcat7'.

I believe the issue is the same as this bug: [ASF Bugzilla – Bug 52467](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52467)

This is part of my first Server 2012 setup and I am unsure as to how to either grant permission or prevent it from starting. My Google-fu on this has been weak and I was unable to locate any information on automatically starting programs for this OS.

For reference, this issue is almost an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028274/unable-to-open-the-service-tomcat7), however the answer provided there does not seem to apply to Server 2012 in the same manner.

Could someone please explain to me what I need to do to resolve this issue or point me to a resource that can enable me do the same? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the logs, and also the windows event log, to get more detail on what exactly it is being denied access to.